# How many meteors hit the moon every day or in how many days does a new meteor hit the moon?

Tags: the-moon, meteor

What is the frequency of meteor strikes on the moon per day?

Answer (score 4):

We generally like you to check google before posting questions here.  I posed your question to google and amongst other links, I got these:

http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2006/13jun_lunarsporadic/
http://www.slate.com/blogs/bad_astronomy/2014/02/24/lunar_impact_video_of_an_asteroid_hitting_the_moon.html

Per Bill cook in the top link:

> No one knows exactly how many meteoroids hit the Moon every day. By monitoring the flashes, we can learn how often and how hard the Moon gets hit."

And in the second one:

> The Moon is smaller and has less gravity than Earth, so it gets hit less often than we do.

Both articles mention MIDAS (the Moon Impacts Detection and Analysis System).  Since the first link is from 2006, perhaps soon we will have a good estimate for you.

Comment: I had seen that link, but I thought someone over here might have more information.

Comment: Google brought me here.

Comment: That strikes me as hilarious.  Google's definitive answer becomes a reference to what Google said 12 years ago.